# How to overdrive a 5W IR LED for laser tag

Tags: infrared, amperage, remote-control, switching-regulator

I am a bit of a noob regarding electronics, but hey, I guess I need to start somewhere.

Here is the premise:
I want to build the Arduino Laser Tag [Link:](https://www.instructables.com/Duino-Tagger/) and all went fine until I stumbled upon overdriving the IR - LED to increase the range of the signal transmission.

I got myself a couple of 5W (730nm 2-2,2V, 850nm 1,6-1,8V, 940nm 1,4-1,6V) 1200mA 45mil LEDs by Hotred. As all parts on Aliexpress they come cheap but without data sheets. Since I want to overdrive them I figured a save way would be to double the amperage to 2400mA at max value +0,4V since a comparable LED with data sheet stated it would be within limits if the pulse cycle would be max 1/10 duty cycle , 0,1ms Pulse width.

Now my question is how can I secure the required amperage, powering the module with a 1s Lipo (3,7 V), since the device needs to be portable.
I have looked into DC-DC switchmode current LED driver boards and the LM317. Would the switchmode driver induce noise into the signal transmission (probably sent at 38kHz)?
The LM317 doesn’t support enough amperage but would a similar regulator work regarding wattage, since those a very short burst of IR signals?

I hope you can lead me in the right direction. Google tried to help but here I am - not a bit closer to an answer...

Comment: How good are the lens on these parts? That can make a bigger difference to have a 10deg lens with standard 100mA LEDs than  160 deg with no lens LEDs at 2.4A. In any case any active current limiter cct design ought to work with allowance for the drop voltage.

Comment: I would strongly recommend building it at the standard 5W limit.  Get it working and then try over driving it later.  A 5W LED is super bright, you may not need to over drive it at all.  You're efforts are much better spent on providing adequate heat sinking for the LED!

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  I am using a planoconvex lens in front of the LED so that I can create parallel light beams. One is in optical glass and another in acrylic since I am not sure if glass of lower quality can have an effect on IR light. As for the active current limiter; do I need to limit instead of amplify? Do you have any concrete components in mind? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Aaron even with the conservative limit I need to supply 1200mA. How can I do that being powered with a 1s 3.7V Lipo? 
The 2mm heat sink is more than enough because the LED is fired for only microseconds.

Comment: Your battery is more than capable of supplying enough voltage and current to drive the LED even at 2400mA. Driving LEDs is always about limiting the current from your supply to operate the LED safely.

Comment: current limiter circuits depend on your efficiency requirements for power drop to a string of around 3 to to 3.2V from 3.6 Battery avg. .. many designs exist on this site. Each LED a saturation resistance that raises voltage with current approx 1/Pd ohms.